# Is it possible to use multiple parameters in SonarQube search API?

Tags: search, parameters, sonarqube

After some time spent scouring google and looking through the Sonar Qube API documentation, along with trying a few permutations on common patterns, I have arrived to the point where I am wondering if it is even possible to use multiple parameters when doing an issue search in SonarQube's API.

Purpose of search is to populate a team radiator with issue data from Sonarqube.  This data will be combined with build data from other sources (Or else I would just link to the SonarQube display page)

current configured URL to api is:

https://sonarqubesitehere.com/api/issues/search?=projectKeys=com.projectnamehere

(This is dummy code with names changed to protect the innocent)

I would like to be able to add a second parameter to this search that allows me to receive only major (or minor) issues that belong to the specific project I specify.      the search term for that search is /search?severities=MAJOR

Anyone wrangled with this particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the WS API on [sonarqube.com](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/issues/search) or your own instance like: `https://your-sonarqube.com/web_api/api/issues/search`.

Here's an example of [api/issues/search](https://sonarqube.com/api/issues/search?p=1&ps=50&s=FILE_LINE&asc=true&additionalFields=_all&resolved=false&types=BUG&severities=BLOCKER&projectUuids=AVLL_OKkLP-CHyQAZDV8%2Cb38e4f29-df5f-491e-9118-a0a4f5cda406) with several parameters

Answer (score 0):

Hummmm... Provided that you read the [Web API documentation for /issues/search](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/issues/search), and that you know how to correctly write a URL that uses parameters, then it's quite easy to find that the solution is the following:

```
https://<your_server>/api/issues/search?projectKeys=project1Key,project2Key&severities=MINOR,MAJOR
```

Live example on SonarQube.com: https://sonarqube.com/api/issues/search?projectKeys=clang,git&severities=BLOCKER